# Error in "birthdeath" function (phylogenetic tree analysis)

Tags: r, lapack, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I want to determine birth and death rate of a given phylogenetic tree using `birthdeath` of the `ape` package, and I get the following error:

```
birthdeath(phy)

Error in solve.default(out$hessian) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nlm(function(p) dev(p[1], p[2]), c(0.1, 0.2), hessian = TRUE) :
  NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
2. etc...
```

The tree `phy` is ultrametric and appears to be fine, `checkValidPhylo` is true (in particular all edges have positive lengths). It plots just fine and looks normal...

I can upload the tree if need be.

Comment: Posting the tree would probably be necessary to fix this problem

Comment: You now find the full three in the edit.

Comment: The problem seems to be the length of the branches (scaling the branch lengths back by a factor of 1000 causes the function to run without error). I would recommend posting to the r-sig phylo mailing group about what to do.

Comment: interesting....
i'll do that! thank you very much